# Validate debian changelog

Tags: debian, packaging

In the project I'm in we build debian packages to distribute our software. The changelog is edited by a couple of committers and tends to be invalid.

Is there a way to check if the changelog is valid without the need to run a full "debuild"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dch` is a tool for editing changelogs. It will complain if the changelog is invalid I believe. (You could also encourage the other committers to use this to avoid the problem in the first place!)

`dpkg-source` reads the changelog file when building the source. That would make quite a reasonable "sanity" check, but doesn't do a full build.

Comment: Our team develops on ubuntu, mac and windows workstations so dch is not an option for all developers. dpkg-source gives a benefit over building the package(s). So the answer is accepted :)

Comment: @Saintedlama dch is just a perl script - it should be reasonably easy to make it run anywhere.